# pagination issue with user display per page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I was following a tutorial on basic php tables to show the users with pagination:

http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/

the problem that i have is my platform does not support MySQL so i change it to MySQLi

the second problem is that the it should display only one user per page but it just show all of them in 1 page and when click on for example on page 2 it is show me error page

this is an image to better description :

http://store2.up-00.com/2014-02/1391920754996.jpg

and this is the code that i am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');


        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                 echo "<tr>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['first_name']; 
                 $lname = $row['last_name'];

                  echo "<tr><td>";
                 echo  $id; 
                  echo "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td>";
                 echo $fname;
                  echo "<td>";
                 echo $lname;
                  echo "</td></tr>"; 

                 }


         echo "</td></tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One user per page, and you make `$per_page = 2;`? Don't follow that code though, at least find a tutorial which has the basic sense to use sql `LIMIT` clauses.

Comment: In addition to what @Wrikken brought up, you're grabbing everything from the result rather than looping from start to the limits you're dealing with.

Comment: sorry i change it to 1 user and i follow the tutorial on this page :  http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/    and it work fine on there tutorial  : http://www.falkencreative.com/forum/records/view-paginated.php?page=1  i do not know what is the error with my code   thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't fix your existing script, so I found a pagination script that I modified and has worked for me.

You will undoubtingly want to modify it, but it works.

Just change the DB credentials and other things you will find throughout the script.

There are a few comments in it also on commented-out options.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users ";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query2);
// Here we have the total row count
$rows = $row[0];
// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 1;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1; // do not change this
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

// This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit
$sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users ORDER BY id ASC $limit";

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Names (<b>$rows</b>)";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}

$dynamicList = '';
        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        // echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th>";

echo "<tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
/*
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["first_name"];
    $price = $row["last_name"];
*/

$id = $row['id'];
$fname = $row['first_name']; 
$lname = $row['last_name'];

echo "<tr><td>";
echo  $id; 
echo "</td>"; 
echo "<td>";
echo $fname;
echo "<td>";
echo $lname;
echo "</td></tr>"; 

// you can use and modify this below
// the <!-- and --> tags can be taken out. Those are regular HTML comment tags.
    $dynamicList .= "

<!--
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='pager.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='pager.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'> (link) <span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>
-->
              ";
}
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div#pagination_controls{font-size:21px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>
  <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?></p>
  <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is working perfectly as i want but i did not understand the <!--and --> tag so i take it out  i do not know how to thank you @Fred -ii- thank you thank you so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. You can just click the `White checkmark` till it turns `Green` to accept my answer and that will also close the question as being answered. The `<!--` and `-->` are plain HTML comment tags, that does the same for PHP's comment tags `//` so if you have an image or something else later on, you can just remove them. Remove them for now and you will see what it will do. Don't worry, you won't break anything but it may produce errors. Dont worry about it, just put the comments back in the way it was if you want. ;-) @user3029453

Comment: Hi @Fred -ii- i try to add more field like email and phone number but it is not working it is giving me an error an undefined index: email

Comment: Under `$lname = $row['last_name'];` add `$email = $row['email'];` and under `echo $fname; echo "<td>";` add `echo $email; echo "<td>";` making sure you have a column named `email` - Please follow the same convention as I mentioned in my answer. I can't keep writing code. You need to learn this stuff. I don't mind helping, but this you need to figure out things out for yourself. @user3029453